# Stuck in a problem in permutation and combination.

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus, permutations, binomial-coefficients

I am solving problems in permutation & combination and stuck in this problem.

Two players $P_1$ and $P_2$ play a series of $2n$ games. Each game can result in either a win or a loss for $P_1$. Find the total number of ways in which $P_1$ can win the series of these games?

**My try**

$P_1$ must win $(n+r)$ games $(r=1, 2, 3, ..., n)$

Required number of ways is $\sum\limits^{n}_{r=1}  {^{2n}}C_{n+r}$

$\sum\limits^{n}_{r=1}  {^{2n}}C_{n+r}= ^{2n}C_{n+1}+ ^{2n}C_{n+2}+\cdots+ ^{2n}C_{2n}$

I want to know whether my approach is right and how to solve the above binomial series further?
Any hint will be of great help.

Comment: Do they play $2n$ or $2^n$ games?

Comment: @G.Sassatelli Thanks. Edited the typo.

Comment: "each game can result in either a win or a loss for $P_1$". Are strikes impossible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach is correct.

As for the second question, consider that

$$\sum_{k=0}^n {n\choose k}=2^n,\ \ \ {n\choose k}={n\choose n-k}$$

Hence

$$\sum_{k=n+1}^{2n}{2n\choose k}=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=n+1}^{2n}\left[{2n\choose k}+{2n\choose 2n-k}\right]=\frac{1}{2}\left(\sum_{k=n+1}^{2n}{2n\choose k}+\sum_{s=n+1}^{2n}{2n\choose 2n-s}\right)\stackrel{\star}{=}\\\stackrel{\star}{=}\frac{1}{2}\left(\sum_{k=n+1}^{2n}{2n\choose k}+\sum_{t=0}^{n-1}{2n\choose t}\right)=\frac{1}{2}\left(\sum_{k\neq n}{n\choose k}\right)=\\=\frac{1}{2}\left(-{2n\choose n}+\sum_{k=0}^{2n}{2n\choose k}\right)=\frac{2^{2n}-{2n\choose n}}{2}$$

Where $(\star)$ is obtained by making the substitution $t:=2n-s$.

Indeed, if $s=n+1,\ldots, 2n$, then $2n-s=n-1,\ldots,0$.

Comment: Can you elaborate 2nd and 3rd step? Final answer given in my book is $\frac{1}{2} (2^{2n}-2\times \dbinom{2n}{n} )$

Comment: @RaviKumar, the formula in your book fails for $n=1$. Indeed, $P_1$ has exactly $1$ way of winning (winning *both* games), while yours says $0$.

Comment: @RaviKumar I elaborated.

Comment: Thanks for elaboration. I checked both yours and my books answer for n=2 and n=3 but none of them are giving the correct result. Can you please verify this? Thanks.

Comment: @RaviKumar $n=2$, winning possibilities ($1=$win.$0=$loss):
$$1111\\1110\\1101\\1011\\0111$$
My formula says: $$\frac{2^4-{4\choose 2}}{2}=\frac{16-6}{2}=5$$

$n=3$, winning possibilities ($1=$win.$0=$loss):
$$111111\\111110\\111101\\111011\\110111\\101111\\011111\\111100\\111010\\110110\\101110\\011110\\111001\\110101\\101101\\011101\\110011\\101011\\011011\\100111\\010111\\001111$$
My formula:
$$\frac{2^6-{6\choose 3}}{2}=\frac{64-20}{2}=\frac{44}{2}=22$$
Before I check all the $93$ results for $n=4$, did I miss something in your question?

Comment: Thanks a lot. You have great patience.

Answer (score 0):

**Hints**:

- how many different ways are there for a game?
- how many different ways are there to end up with a strike?
- the number of ways $P_1$ can win equals the number of ways $P_2$ can win.